# Will I be turned down for a car loan?

Tags: loans, credit, car

To make a long story short I was working at the same place since I was 18 the past 3 years, and left on good terms two months ago and now I'm self employed. I'm making much more now than I was at my last job and pulling several thousand a week. I want to buy a car in the 80k-100k range and will be putting down $30k or so. Seeing as how I have no tangible cogent proof of income as I've just started two months ago, bank statements only going back two months with my current income, etc. I'm going to have my father cosign who has solid proof of income and a decent credit score as well so they should go off his financials.

Considering I'm putting 30% down and having my father cosign is there any chance I would be turned down for a loan on a $100k car?

How should I go about this?

Comment: Also I should add that I'm okay with paying high interest on this loan as it will boost my credit score in the long term and plan to pay it off early.

Comment: Have you built up an emergency fund?As a self-employed person, have you  built up a *large* emergency fund?

Comment: I'm not sure about the auto loan, which is why I haven't added an answer.  Some questions, though: #1 How "several" is "several"?  (Taxes take a big bite out of that.)  #2 What's your credit score?  #3 How "decent" is your father's credit score?  #4 How big of a hurt would it put on him, if you default on the loan, requiring him to pay for it?  #5 Making that much money (and presumably being young with no wife/children/huge mortgage) why don't you just save for a year and pay cash?

Comment: #1. Around $5k a week varies, very stable the market isn't going anywhere. Also I have an emergency fund but won't use it for the car. Around $40k in my savings account. #2. 608 #3. Around 700. #4. I won't and he knows that already. Also my grandfather is a millionaire and could cover it if I fucked up. #5. Because I want a car now and need one I don't have one at all.

Comment: A score of 608 is Poor, and 700 is on the *very* low end of Good.  Someone will loan you the money for a high enough rate, but I **strongly** urge you to show some restraint (meaning "buy a cheaper car").

Comment: You shouldn't be okay with paying a high interest rate just to build a credit history, there's no sense in that. You don't have to pay interest to improve a credit score.

Comment: Even with a $250k income, a $100k car is an incredible mistake. Buy yourself a $30k car for cash now. Then if you really want the ridiculous car, save up and pay cash in a year or two. Hopefully, you'll realize between now and then how awful that purchase would be, and change your mind. If not, you'll have an extravagant car and no debt.

Answer (score 4):

> Considering I'm putting 30% down and having my father cosign is there
>   any chance I would be turned down for a loan on a $100k car?

According to [BankRate](http://www.bankrate.com/financing/cars/what-credit-score-is-needed-to-buy-a-car/), the average credit score needed to buy a new car is 714, but they also show average interest rates at 6.39% for new-car loans to people with credit scores in the 601-660 range. High income certainly helps offset credit score to some extent.

Not every bank/dealership does things the same way. Being self-employed you'd most likely be required to show 2 years of tax returns, and they'd use those as a basis for your income rather than whatever you have made recently. If using a co-signer, their income matters. Another key factor is debt to income ratio, if too much of someone's income is already spoken for by other debts a lender will shy away.

So, yes, there's a chance, given all the information we don't know and the variability with lender policies, that you could be turned down for a car loan.

> How should I go about this?

If you're set on pursuing the car loan, just go talk to some lenders. You'll want to shop around for a good rate anyway, so no need to speculate just go find out. Include the dealership as a potential financing option, they can have great rates.

Personally, I'd get a much cheaper car. Your insurance premium on a 100k car will be quite high due to your age. You might be rightly confident in your earning potential, but nothing is guaranteed, situations can change wildly in short order. A new car is not a good investment or a value-retaining asset, so why bother going into debt for one if you don't have to? If you buy something in cash now, you could upgrade in a few years without financing if your earning prediction holds and would save quite a bit in car insurance and interest over the years between.